# How in nuxt.js include ".html" suffix to page?

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

How to include ".html" suffix to page address? For example: test_page -> test_page.html

Answer (score 0):

One solution what I found is  to include in /pages folder our file like this: page.html.vue